# Azure Functions not visible on Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Lately I've noticed that my HTTP triggered Azure Functions are not visible any more in the WebJob Dashboard. Anyone knows why and how to fix that?

Comment: I noted the my question has been downvoted...since this seems to be the official support contact point for azure functions, I'm wondering why...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after creating a Function App using an ARM template I exported from a manually created Function App.

In order to fix this issue you need a storage account to be availble in the function app resource group.

Add these two key/value pairs to the Function App `ApplicationSettings`:

```
key:    AzureWebJobsDashboard
Value:  DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="your storage account name";AccountKey="you storage account key"

key:    AzureWebJobsStorage
Value:  DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="your storage account name";AccountKey="you storage account key"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Webjobs related to Azure Functions would be visible under the Functions tab. If you click the Functions button on the top right corner of the dasboard or go to this url

```
https://<YourFunctionApp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions
```

you should be able to see Webjobs related to Azure Functions there.

Also would you mind sharing your function app name or the first part of your subscription guid so we can check if something is not right with your app.

Comment: Yes, I know the "Function" tab, the problem is that the tab is totally empty. Also the "Monitor" page (on the Function tab) is empy...while the function has been invoked a lot of times....

Comment: I understand, We would need the function app name or the first part of your subscription guid to see what is going on.

Do you still have the functions on your app or are you looking for invocation history?

Comment: I'm looking for invocation history. I prefer not to disclose any private data here, I'm sure you understand....

Comment: There is a way you can share your site name without posting it on the public forum. Please refer to the following link.
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly